# Using Linq to group objects that contain a list field

Tags: c#, linq, collectionviewsource

I have a class, let's name it as MyClass, with a public field of type `IList<AnotherType>`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public IList<AnotherType> MyListProperty {get;}
}
```

I also have a list of MyClass objects in my app:

```
list = new List<MyClass>();
```

I want to get a group from this "list", specifically 
`IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<MyClass,AnotherType>>` using Linq, which will be used as a source to a CollectionViewSource and will be shown to the user as a grouped ListView. How can I do this?

In other words, I want to merge the "list" into a grouped enumerable with the keys being `MyClass` instances and values being `MyClass.MyListProperty`.

Comment: Try edit with an example, it is bit confusing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
list.SelectMany(x => x.MyListProperty.GroupBy(y => x));
```

This returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<MyClass, AnotherType>>`. To make it an `IOrderedEnumerable`, you need to add `.OrderBy(x => x.SomeOrderingProperty);` at the end.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! Sorry, it was very hard to explain but you still managed to understand...